# Dataset shared columns: inheritance of folder type

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, managed-metadata-column

Does anyone know why the contents of a dataset might behave as follows? The desired behavior would be for all columns to be inherited from the containing dataset type.

Currently, shared columns successfully update child items except for folders. Folders that are created using windows file explorer on a synced computer will be created with successfully shared columns. However, folders created using the New Item menu on sharepoint.com do not inherit the shared columns. Both folders show as content type folder - the only known difference between these items is how they were instantiated.

Any ideas on diagnosing this problem and explaining the root cause would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you give a little more explanation on the configuration of the content types? For example: 1. What is the version of SharePoint Online are you using? 2. What are the shared columns you use for the content type folder? 3. Do you see the shared columns in the list/library after updating the content type?

Comment: SharePoint through office365, and its a teams site.  There are a variety of shared columns - mostly custom columns.  For all other content types, you can see the shared columns, but not for a folder.

Comment: But you see the shared columns while using windows file explorer? I have tested from my end and I fail to see this behavior. Would it be possible that you provide a screenshot in the original post?

Comment: Oh I see the confusion now.  My comment wasn't that the shared columns are visible in windows file explorer.  Rather, when the files are CREATED using file explorer, that process updates the shared columns.  When the files are created using sharepoint online the shared columns are not updated.  Does this clarify?  I don't think I can share a screenshot sadly.

Comment: Yes, of course. Do you see the columns attached to the Folder content type via Site Content Type page? You can try creating a custom Folder content type and add it to your library, add those shared columns as well. The default Folder Content Type is not modifiable via document library settings.

Comment: @Chelsea_MSFT thank you - this might be a good workaround.  Thank you.  Do you know why the standard Folder content type is only inheriting in one scenario and not in another?

Comment: I’m not sure. Folder content type could be a bit of tricky when managing, but I have not run into anything like this before. Anyway, custom content type would be a better solution when it comes to customization.